# Xbindkeys to make CTRL + ALT act like ALT GR

Tags: linux-mint, xbindkeys

I've been able to get CTRL + ALT working (mostly) with `xbindkeys` and `xvkbd`.
However for it to work I initially have to press it twice. After that it works smoothly.

**Also this doesn't work in some programs such as xed and gnome-terminal and I was wondering why and how to fix this?**

This is my .xbindkeysrc config:

```bash
xvkbd -xsendevent -text '{'"
    m:0x1c + c:18
    Control+Alt+Mod2 + ccedilla

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '}'"
    m:0x1c + c:19
    Control+Alt+Mod2 + agrave

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '@'"
    m:0x1c + c:11
    Control+Alt+Mod2 + eacute

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '#'"
    m:0x1c + c:12
    Control+Alt+Mod2 + quotedbl

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '['"
    m:0x1c + c:34
    Control+Alt+Mod2 + dead_circumflex

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text ']'"
    m:0x1c + c:35
    Control+Alt+Mod2 + dollar
```

Why does this not work in xed or gnome-terminal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be better to bind altgr to a never-use key instead e.g. capslock.

Comment: @IporSircer why and how?